# If $f$ and $g$ are non-constant and periodic functions of minimum period $T>0$, then T is period of $h(x)=af(x)+bg(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, trigonometry

The problems of finding the minimum positive periods of functions are always quite complicated. I remembered the following, it being trivially true that

> If $f$ and $g$, $f\ne g$, are non-constant and periodic functions of minimum period $T>0$, then T is period of $h(x)=af(x)+bg(x)$. ($a, b\ne0$ e $a\ne b$)

My question is, is $T$ the smallest period of $h$ as well?

Comment: Since $h(x+T)=h(x)$ assuming that there is a period $0\lt t\lt T$ such that $h(x+t)=h(x)$ we must have $T=nt$ for some integer and
$$h(x)=h(x+\dfrac{T}{n})=af(x+\dfrac{T}{n})+bg(x+\dfrac{T}{n})= af(x)+bg(x)\\ a(f(x+\dfrac{T}{n})-f(x))+b(g(x+\dfrac{T}{n})-g(x))=0$$ This being true for all $x$ since $ab\ne0$  we have for all $x$
$$f(x+\dfrac{T}{n})=f(x)\\g(x+\dfrac{T}{n})=g(x)$$ which is absurde.

Comment: What about $h(x)=f(x)-f(x)$ ? More precisely $g(x)=f(x),$ $a=1,$ $b=-1.$

Comment: @Piquito

I didn't quite understand the part where you concluded that if $ab\ne 0$ then... could you be more specific?

Comment: And intended $f\ne g$ @RyszardSzwarc

Comment: What about $h(x)=2(f(x)/2)-f(x)$ ? More precisely $g(x)=f(x)/2$, $a=-1$, $b=2$.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe It's very nice.Thanks

Comment: Even the  linear independence is not sufficient:   $g(x)=f(x)+f(2x)$ and $a=1,$ $b=-1?$

Comment: @CPMP: You say $a$ and $b$ are  nonzero and I say $ab\ne0$ Does not see you that we say the same?